# asp.net -> google maps api -> Best way to create a map from an .aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps

Ok, I am working on a project where an end user will click on a link within a grid that will open a new window. (.aspx page)  I have been researching on how to create a google map from the newly opened .aspx page with out writing a bunch of dynamic javascript in the code behind and then registering the clientscript to the page.  I have done this in the past but it really isn't pretty and is really cumbersome if you ever need to come back and change things.

The initial version of this map will have a route with multiple points present, a later version of this will provide the ability to have multiple routes within the same map (just to give you an overview of what the end goal is)  An example would be a route with points LA to Vegas to Austin.

So, I know this is a very general/vague question, but what I am trying to figure out is the best way to generate a google map from a .aspx page without writing dynamic sql, I am sure others have stumbled across this issue previously.  Thoughts/Comments, everything is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Be warned that if you're going to be high-volume, Google starts charging for access to maps above a certain request limit (can't remember it). We ended up having to switch to Bing (ugh!) as Google was going to be too expensive (and getting an answer from their sales team was like pulling teeth)

Comment: Hmmm, we already use them quite a bit, but that is a very good point because this will used at a much higher volume than our previous versions.  I would like to know those ranges if anyone has them.

Comment: Sorry, that was the wrong link... http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#usagelimits

Comment: Note that other components you may be using in conjunction with the maps may have more restrictive limits eg the Places API is limited to 1,000/day: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#Limits

Comment: Thanks for the information, I will be passing this on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some components floating around online, but one technique that's worked well for me is to use a hidden field to hold the address/coordinates/etc., and use the hidden field to populate the map:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map = null; 
    var geocoder = null;                
    var address = "<%=hdnMapAddress.Value%>";       

    showAddress = function() {
        var mapContainer = $get("<%=pnlMap.ClientID%>");
        if (mapContainer){        
            if (GBrowserIsCompatible()){      
                geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();                      
                map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("<%=pnlMap.ClientID%>"));               
            }                    
            if (geocoder){ 
                geocoder.getLatLng(address, 
                    function(point){                                                                
                        var marker = new GMarker(point);
                        if (marker){
                            map.setCenter(point, 12);                         
                            map.addOverlay(marker);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                        }                                                              
                    }
                );             
            }              
        }  
    }  
</script>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnMapAddress" runat="server" /> 
<asp:Panel ID="pnlMap" runat="server" Height="230">
    <!-- map content -->
</asp:Panel>
```

Code-behind:

```
hdnMapAddress.Value = "123 Test St, Providence, RI 02904";
```

Comment: That is a good solution.  I could write all my code and pass in hidden variables to the javascript in order to keep the javascript code out of the codebehind.

Comment: Overall a good solution, but the javascript above is using the deprecated Google Maps API 2.  I'd suggest using Google Maps API 3 instead.

Comment: @duncan: Good point. I lifted this from an app that's a few years old. I'll try to update shortly.

Comment: Ok, turns out I am going to need to pass an array, any idea on how to do that with using hidden fields?

Comment: That is correct.  Lats and Longs to be specific, I was trying to figure out how to do a multidimensional array, but unable to do that, think I am going to have to go with a regular array to a hidden field as a .tostring value then parse it on the clientside back into an array and use it that way.  I don't know any other way to do it.  Ideally, I could just pass the array itself to a hiddenfield but don't think that is possible.